# Laravel Eloquent getting all 'with' relationship without specifying one by one

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

My relationships is something like:

```
player
   sub
       something
   sub-2
   sub-3
       something
           foobar
   sub-4
```

I can get player by id with its sub like this:

```
Player::with('sub.something','sub-2','sub-3.something.foobar','sub-4')->find($id);
```

However I had to specify each 'with' relationship manually.
Is it possible to just get everything on the child relationship (hasMany/hasOne) in one query?
Something like:

```
Player::with(everything())->find($id);
```

Comment: if you define what 'everything' is ... the model does not know what methods are relationship methods ... so sure if you wanted to create some method/macro that adds all those `with`s to a builder you could easily do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, relationships are expensive to get so you need to be explicit with what you need to load each time. You can however specify which relationships are always eager loaded on the model:

```
class Player extends Model {
    protected $with = [ 'sub.something','sub-2','sub-3.something.foobar','sub-4' ];
    // Rest of model
}
```

This way you won't need to specify `::with` every time when loading a model.

Comment: is it effect globally in a model?

Comment: Yes it's global but it just saves you the trouble of having to do `with::` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use Eager Loading to get the model with related data:
[eager-loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Player::with(['sub'])->find($id);
```

it will return all subs of a player.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make a clear example but 'sub', 'sub-2', 'sub-3' etc are all different models. I want to avoid specifying like this: with('sub','sub-2.something','sub-3') etc but instead I want to do it just with('all()') or something like that, if that's possible.
Otherwise I'll have to specify each relationship manually.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid Ok I see. You can use your code into a function too and use it everywhere and change everytime.